# How do I print the value of a tuple, that is inside a list, recursively?

Tags: python

I have a list with tuples inside it. The formatting is as follows:

```
>>> list1 = [('CN=blah,OU=blah,DC=blah', {'mail': ['email1@mail.com']}),
('CN=blah,OU=blah,DC=blah', {'mail': ['email2@mail.com']})]`
```

printing list1 produces the following output:

```
>>> print list1
[('CN=blah,OU=blah,DC=blah', {'mail': ['email1@mail.com']}),
 ('CN=blah,OU=blah,DC=blah', {'mail': ['email2@mail.com']})]`
```

I want the output to only list the e-mail addresses, like this:

```
email1@mail.com, email2@mail.com
```

or this:

```
['email1@mail.com','email2@mail.com']
```

How exactly do I accomplish this?

Comment: Will the list corresponding to 'mail' ever have more than just one email address?  If not, are you committed to using a list type there where a string would do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list1 = [('CN=blah,OU=blah,DC=blah', {'mail': ['email1@mail.com']}), ('CN=blah,OU=blah,DC=blah', {'mail': ['email2@mail.com']})]
print [x[1]["mail"][0] for x in list1]
['email1@mail.com', 'email2@mail.com']
```

`x[1]` is the second subelement which is your `dict` so `x[1]["mail"]` uses the key `mail` to get the value from the dict and `[0]` extracts just the email from the `list`.

If you want to extract the strings you can use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on the list of emails:

```
" ".join([x[1]["mail"][0] for x in list1])
email1@mail.com email2@mail.com
```

If there is a chance there will be `dicts` without the key `mail` you would want to check if the key exists first with `if "mail" in x[1]`:

```
[x[1]["mail"][0] for x in list1 if "mail" in x[1]]
```

If not all your second elements are **not** dicts you can use isinstace to check if it is a dict first:

```
" ".join([x[1]["mail"][0] for x in list1 if isinstance(x[1],dict) and  "mail" in x[1] ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! When I use your technique as presented above, it works great. But for some reason when I used the list produced by my script, I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ldaptest.py", line 13, in <module>
    print [x[1]["mail"][0] for x in mylist]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: ah ok so not all your second elements are dicts? I will add another check, did you use `if "mail" in x[1]`?

Comment: `[x[1]["mail"][0] for x in list1 if "mail" in x[1]]` WORKS! Thank you so much, you are the man Padraic!

Comment: No worries, you're welcome, I will leave the `isinstance` as you could technically have `"mail" in x[1]` and it not be a dict.